# Overiding comparison methods in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I come across this code from one of my friends. It is a test for overiding comparison methods in Python. When i ran the code i got this:

True

True

True

and this: "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'A' and 'B'"

If that is the case, why the same error did not happen with "a1 == b1"?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
class B:
    def __init__(self, x):
        A.__init__(self, x)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.x < other.x
a1 = A(1)
b1 = B(1)
print(b1 == a1)
print(a1 == b1)

a2 = A(2)
b2 = B(1)
print(b2 < a2)

a3 = A(1)
b3 = B(2)
print(a3 < b3)
```

Comment: Did you forget to say `class B(A)` so that an instance of `B` is also an instance of `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement `__lt__` on `A` if comparison doesn't make sense for `A` normally; `B` can do all the heavy lifting for comparisons between `A` and `B`, but you need to implement the reflected comparison operators for this to work.

The problem here is that `A` doesn't implement `__lt__`, so Python will execute `a3 < b3` by using the reflected operator from `B`, making the line test `b3 > a3`. But you didn't implement `__gt__` in `B`, so there is no way to reflect the operation.

The simplest fix (recommended in general if you implement any of the comparison operations) is to [use `functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to expand the single implemented operator to the whole rich comparison suite:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class B:
     ... rest of B unchanged ...
```

That's it; your code will just work, as that decoration will ensure `__gt__` is defined in terms of `__lt__`/`__eq__`, so the attempt to flip the comparison will succeed.

You could equivalently define each of the operations one by one, e.g.:

```
class B:
    ... rest of class ...
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.x > other.x
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.x <= other.x
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.x >= other.x
```

but that's tedious and error-prone; use `functools.total_ordering`.

The `==` test worked just fine because equality is reflexive, so the same overload works in either direction when the other operand doesn't implement it; Python tries `a.__eq__(b)` and finds it doesn't work, so it tries `b.__eq__(a)`, since `a == b` is logically equivalent to `b == a`. It's only rich comparisons where the reflected operation uses a different method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `__lt__` in class `A` too:

```python
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.x < other.x
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x):
        A.__init__(self, x)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.x < other.x
a1 = A(1)
b1 = B(1)
print(b1 == a1)
print(a1 == b1)

a2 = A(2)
b2 = B(1)
print(b2 < a2)

a3 = A(1)
b3 = B(2)
print(a3 < b3)
```

And, of course, the same will remain true for the rest of operators. The reason of why that happens is because in `b < a` the method called is `B.__lt__` and in `a < b` the method called is `A.__lt__`. The former method is defined but not the latter.

Btw, you were calling `A`'s contructor in `B`'s constructor. I assume that you want a `B` to be also an `A`, so `B` inherits from `A`. Thats the reason why my code says `class B(A)`.

Comment: Please also comment on the inheritance from  class A in class B `class B(A):` which the OP forgot in his/her code

Comment: Is it really necessary to implement `__lt__` twice, if B inherits from A?

Comment: @Bazingaa. Inheritance is not necessary here. Calling `A.__init__` in `B.__init__` may look weird, but is not in any way illegal.

Comment: @Kevin: No. `__lt__`'s definition could be removed from `B` if it's implemented correctly in the superclass.

Comment: Not at all, @Kevin, I only added the minimal code needed for his/her example to work properly. You can leave that implementation out

Comment: I think we have different standards for what "minimal" comprises, then :-) I would consider "make B inherit from A" to be more minimal than "make B inherit from A, and implement `A.__lt__`"

Comment: Calling `A.__init__` in `B.__init__` may not be illegal, but it's a pattern that you should never use

Comment: @nicholishen There's nothing wrong with calling `A.__init__` instead of `super().__init__`, if that is what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

So I changed you code to add `print` statements to the `__eq__` method, like so:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
class B:
    def __init__(self, x):
        A.__init__(self, x)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('type(self) =', type(self))
        print('type(other) =', type(other))
        return self.x == other.x
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.x < other.x
```

and the results were this:

```
type(self) = <class '__main__.B'>
type(other) = <class '__main__.A'>
True
type(self) = <class '__main__.B'>
type(other) = <class '__main__.A'>
True
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chrx/Dropbox/Documents/Programming/questions/SO_question.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(a3 < b3)
TypeError: unorderable types: A() < B()
```

So even though you only wrote a `__eq__` method for the `B` class, it was used when comparing in the reversed order, `a == b`. This (I believe) is a feature of the Python language that assumes equality operators are reflexive, i.e. `a == b` and `b == a` should have the same result.

However, this property does not apply to the `__lt__` operator in this case, because `a < b` is different from `b < a`.

Comment: This property applies to `__lt__`, it's just that it flips to follow the logic; if `a.__lt__(b)` (`a < b`) isn't implemented, Python tries `b.__gt__(a)` (`b > a`). [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53841231/364696) covers fixing this properly without modifying `A`.